# Disable row highlighting in JFace.TableViewer

Tags: java, jface, tableviewer

I'm using a `TableViewer` to create a table but whenever I hover with the mouse over a cell the whole row gets highlighted but I consider this more confusing than helpful.
What I want is either to highlight nothing when simply hovering or to highlight only the cell the mouse is currently over.

I've looked into several code snippets but I never found something that does what I want.

So how can I achieve the above described behaviour?

Comment: That is usually the native control doing this automatically and isn't controllable. It also varies between platforms, on Mac OS X it only happens when the line has been truncated.

Comment: Hm... bad news. Is there then a way to change the row highlighting to that dotted rectangle it becomes when selecting a cell?

Comment: You can change the highlight for a row which it is selected (although this is hard) but I don't think there is any control over the hover highlight (again Mac OS X doesn't show a dotted rectangle)